# Move static block to top of each category page

Tags: magento

Currently when I add a cms static block into the category pages via category display settings it shows up but inline with the left column. I would like it to appear above, with the left column and products under.

So visually,

instead of:

Left Column | Static Block

```
         | Products
```

I would like it:

```
  Static Block
```

left column | products

any ideas?

Comment: I looks like you would need a custom design. Check out [custom design](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/category-custom-design).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the 2 columns with left-bar.phtml

you have to create a new structural block into the layout

modify the 2columns-left.phtml file

```
.....
    <div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <div class="page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        <div class="main-container col2-left-layout">
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('categorystaticblock'); //<---new block ?>
                <div class="col-main">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    </div>
</div>
.....
```

Now in the catalog.xml declare what's inside you new structural block

```
       <catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>

        <reference name="categorystaticblock">
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="categorystatickblock" as="categorystatickblock" template="catalog/category/staticblock.phtml">
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
....
```

Now create the new file
catalog/category/staticblock.phtml

```
<?php if($this->isContentMode() ||$this->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now remove or coment out from the catalog/category/view.phtml the

```
<?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
```

lines that echo the cms block otherwise you will get it twice on the page

Hope this helps

bye
Giuseppe

Comment: Thanks for the input, I followed the directions and nothing happened. Should I be customizing any of the code?

Comment: No, using layout non modification to the code is needed.

Comment: No, using layout does not need modification to the code is needed.
I've used the above several times...
I suggest debuging the mods by adding an echo "hello" before the getchild... to foind where something is missing..

Answer (score 0):

Following what Giuseppe said it almost worked form me. I spent few more hours to figure out what I am missing. It turns out you have to add a new in your page.xml file around the place where "content" block is defined.

`<block type="core/text_list" name="categorystaticblock" as="categorystaticblock" translate="label">
                <label>Static category content</label>
            </block>`

Also in the XML provided by Giuseppe there is a typo. There has to be a / at the end of the "categorystatickblock" block.